# Copy multiple Range from Sheet1 based on a conditionand paste it in Alongside in Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with my vba code in excel. I am trying to get excel automatically copy the contents of multiple ranges (B, C, D, F, G) from sheet1 based on a condition to sheet2 as side by side.
example how this will look like:

[image: Image Example]

this is my code which only copy range B to D :

```
Sub CopyButton()
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 5
For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
If cell.Value > 0 Then
r=cell.row
range("B" & r & ":D" & r).Copy Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
i = i + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a second copy line `Range("F" & r & ":G" & r).Copy Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4)`

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you very much its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be accomplished with an [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) to isolate the rows and a [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) of the [Range.SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) using the **xlCellTypeVisible** [xlCellType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) option.

```
Sub xferBCDFG()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<>0"
            With Union(.Range("B:D"), .Range("F:G")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1)
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: filter_rows_union_columns]
            <sup>Sample data on Sheet1</sup>

[image: filter_rows_union_columns_results]
            <sup>Results on Sheet2</sup>